# Can I request previous sample time more efficiently in this Oracle SQL statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group, oracle9i

I have a fairly simple Oracle 9 table made up of a timestamp, itemid number and value.

---

```
DT_RECORDDATE    ITEMID     SYSTEMID    VALUE
2019-04-04       25         97          1
2019-04-05       19         55          1
2019-04-06       25         44          1
2019-04-03       44         29          2
```

The primary key is DT_RECORDDATE and ITEMID.

---

What I'd like to do is get the most recent **DT_RECORDDATE** or even better, the most recent **VALUE**, for each of my item IDs.

For the above table, I should get something like this...

```
DT_RECORDDATE    ITEMID 
2019-04-05       19
2019-04-06       25
2019-04-03       44
```

My current solution is to grab the highest date stamp.

```
SELECT MAX(DT_RECORDDATE), ITEMID 
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE DT_RECORDDATE <= to_date('2019-05-05 10:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') 
  AND SYSTEMID=1 
GROUP BY ITEMID
```

However on large tables, this is taking a LOT of time.

There are 50 distinct IDs in the result set (more than that in the table, but they are filtered out by the WHERE clause).

Outside making new database keys (which the administrator isn't overly interested in doing), is there any way I can improve the timing of this query? It takes several seconds to run on the database, which contains a few million records.

I'm aware that people tend to use `PARTITION` and `RANK()` to improve performance, but I must admit that I'm not super familiar with how they work or if it's going to be applicable in this case, as I haven't spent much time with Oracle.

They are not currently able to upgrade to a more modern version of Oracle Server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using window functions is typically the most efficient solution. The following should work on your ancient Oracle version as well:

```
SELECT dt_recorddate, itemid, systemid, value
FROM (
  SELECT dt_recorddate, itemid, systemid, value, 
         row_number() over (partition by itemid order by dt_recorddate desc) as rn
  FROM mytable 
  WHERE dt_recorddate <= to_date('2019-05-05 10:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') 
    AND systemid=1 
) 
where rn = 1;
```

Alternatively the following *might* be faster:

```
SELECT dt_recorddate, itemid, systemid, value
FROM mytable m
  JOIN (
    SELECT itemid, max(dt_recorddate) as max_date
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE dt_recorddate <= to_date('2019-05-05 10:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') 
      AND systemid=1 
    GROUP BY itemid
  ) x on x.itemid = m.itemid and x.max_date = dt_recorddate;
```

I don't remember if Oracle 9 already supported the cleaner explicit JOIN operator, if not you need to rewrite the above to

```
SELECT dt_recorddate, itemid, systemid, value
FROM mytable m, 
     (SELECT itemid, max(dt_recorddate) as max_date
      FROM mytable 
      WHERE dt_recorddate <= to_date('2019-05-05 10:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') 
        AND systemid=1 
      GROUP BY itemid) x 
where x.itemid = m.itemid and x.max_date = dt_recorddate;
```

Comment: Looks great - thanks for such a complete answer. I'll check it out tomorrow and mark the answer then!